# How do I run a Maven Plugin on all modules?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin, mojo

I have a custom plugin that I run on all our projects as part of the release:perform goal.

We are just starting to use multi-module builds, and I notice that my plugin only runs at the top module.  What do I have to do to my plugin to make it run on all the modules individually at the end of the release?  Do I have to iterate through them in the plugin code itself?  If so, is there an example of doing that, because from what I see, MavenProject.getModules() just returns a list of String names of those modules, and I can't see how to get info for those modules (my plugin needs the groupId:artifactId:version of each, and in this case, the modules do not always have the same version).

I've tried with and without @aggregator, but that doesn't change anything with respect to my problem.

I'm assuming this is the same case as running the plugin directly (not tied to a phase) from CLI, which also only runs on the top-level of the project, and reports SKIPPED for all the sub-modules.

I am using Maven 3.0.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem with my Maven plugin.  It was only being invoked once (generally for the first module in the reactor), and I eventually traced it to the fact that my plugin had the Maven annotation "@requiresProject false".  It seems that the Maven Reactor only invokes such plugins once.  Once I switched to "@requiresProject true", my mojo was invoked once for each module.  I wasn't hooking into release:perform, so YMMV.

As for accessing all the modules, instead of using MavenProject.getModules() which gives their names, you could inject their MavenProject objects like this:

```
   /**
    * The projects in the reactor.
    *
    * @parameter expression="${reactorProjects}"
    * @readonly
    */
   private List<MavenProject> reactorProjects;
```

Watch out for @aggregator when binding to lifecycle phases. "When bound to a lifecycle, an aggregator mojo can have some nasty side-effects. It can force the execution of the ... lifecycle phase to execute ahead of time, and can result in builds which end up executing the ... phase twice." [ref](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/assemblies-sect-basics.html)

[How do you force a maven MOJO to be executed only once at the end of a build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132976/how-do-you-force-a-maven-mojo-to-be-executed-only-once-at-the-end-of-a-build) has some alternatives to @aggregator.

Comment: All of the above ways of doing it work for me:
- @requiresProject true makes the plugin run on all modules (without @aggregator)
- passing in the reactorProjects also worked great, and lets me run the plugin once for the whole reactor which is much more efficient for me

Answer (score 2):

Using the new `maven-plugin-annotations` you can also inject:

```
@Component
private MavenSession session;
```

and call `session.getProjects()` (Maven 3) or `session.getSortedProjects()` (2).

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `@seanf`'s answer didn't work for me (maybe because I use a much newer version of Maven?!) so I modified the code to accept the `@Parameter` annotation and it worked !

```
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${reactorProjects}", required = true, readonly = true)
private List<MavenProject> reactorProjects;
```